# como hacer el formato geojson en java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, geojson

tengo una pregunta , como haria este formato en java con hibernate y mysql ?

```
{
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [{
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-77.032, 38.913]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Mapbox',
      description: 'Washington, D.C.'
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-122.414, 37.776]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Mapbox',
      description: 'San Francisco, California'
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, te refieres a como podrías simular esta estructura en base de datos a traves de clases?

Comment: Muy buenas Tardes. Por supuesto que si mi estimado a eso me refiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva:

```
public class Geometry
{
  private String type;

  public String getType() { return this.type; }

  public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }

  private ArrayList<double> coordinates;

  public ArrayList<double> getCoordinates() { return this.coordinates; }

  public void setCoordinates(ArrayList<double> coordinates) { this.coordinates = coordinates; }
}

public class Properties
{
  private String title;

  public String getTitle() { return this.title; }

  public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

  private String description;

  public String getDescription() { return this.description; }

  public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
}

public class Feature
{
  private String type;

  public String getType() { return this.type; }

  public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }

  private Geometry geometry;

  public Geometry getGeometry() { return this.geometry; }

  public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) { this.geometry = geometry; }

  private Properties properties;

  public Properties getProperties() { return this.properties; }

  public void setProperties(Properties properties) { this.properties = properties; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  private String type;

  public String getType() { return this.type; }

  public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }

  private ArrayList<Feature> features;

  public ArrayList<Feature> getFeatures() { return this.features; }

  public void setFeatures(ArrayList<Feature> features) { this.features = features; }
}
```

Eso ya es traducible a hibernate.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Si me sirvio.

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que mas te ayudo haciendo click en la paolmita.

Comment: disculpa mi estimado .